# What is the correct FilterObject ORDS syntax?

Tags: json, oracle, oracle-ords

I want to filter the result of a RestApi ORDS, using a FilterObject to send it through the url, but I can't find an example of how to group several operators and and or.

If the FilterObject for this case:

```
where (codigo like 'DACK%' or codigo like 'DO%')
```

Is this:

```
{"$or":[{"codigo":{"$like":"DACK%"}},{"codigo":{"$like":"DO%"}}]}
```

What should be the syntax for the following example:

```
 WHERE VALOR = 'SUPER'
   AND ( CODIGO LIKE 'DACK%'
    OR CODIGO LIKE 'DO%' )
 ORDER BY CODIGO
```

I use ords 19.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'tricky' part is the $or..

I'm going to write an equivalent example using HR.EMPLOYEES, since I don't have your table.

```
GET /ords/hr/employees?q={"job_id":{"$eq":"IT_PROG"},"email":{"$or":[{"$like":"AH%25"},{"$like":"%25VPAT%25"}]},"$orderby":{"salary":"desc"}}
```

Equates to

```
SELECT *
  FROM EMPLOYEES
 WHERE JOB_ID = 'IT_PROG'
   AND ( EMAIL LIKE '%VPAT%'
    OR EMAIL LIKE 'AH%' )
 ORDER BY SALARY DESC
```

Which looks like this

[image]

I have more examples [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/09/some-query-filtering-examples-in-ords/)

This is officially documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/19.2/aelig/developing-REST-applications.html#GUID-091748F8-3D14-402B-9310-25E6A9116B47)